# How to add a ToolTip for an icon inside my CSS file

Tags: css, html, layout

I have the following icon , which is used mainly on most of my asp.net mvc web pages:-

```
<i class=" icon icon-blue icon-star-on "></i>
```

The related CSS classes for this icon is :-

```
 .active .icon32.icon-star-on,.icon32.icon-star-on,.icon32.icon-star-on:hover {background-position : -448px -96px ;}
 .icon.icon-blue,.icons-blue .icon {background-image : url('../img/opa-icons-blue16.png') ;}
```

But I need to add a tootip for the icon, so that when a use move the mouse over the icon to show a tooltip. So is there a way to define the tooltip inside my CSS , so that I do not have to add the tooltip manually on each screen?
Thanks

Comment: After I saw in others answers that 'content' can get attributes I looked into google for info about that. This might help you: http://css-tricks.com/css-content/ Edit: ok I understand that you don't want modify HTML so @LinkinTED answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by using `:after`:

```
.icon:hover:after {
    content: "Your tooltip";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -16px;
    right: -16px;
    width: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Also check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/ZpZ9w/).

Please note that all `.icon` classes get the same tooltip. This is pure CSS solution. If you want them to be different for each icon, you could use different classes, or use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your css:

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #111;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 98;
}
.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #111 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 12px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Add a a title to your icon `title="Tooltip text"` and add the class of `tooltip` to the icon.

Source: http://forrst.com/posts/Simple_pure_CSS_tooltip_with_arrow-BkY

Comment: Does this work for you? In Chrome I have still default title show action. It would be awesome if it would work. I didn't know that content attribute can get something like attr().

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute with the text for the element and use it for hovering. 
I have showed using an anchor tag.

html

```
<a href="#" title="you have hovered">Hover here</a>
```

css

```
.tooltip{
    display:inline;
    position:relative;  
}
.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}
.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

'http://jsfiddle.net/Kxnqx/'

Answer (score 0):

If you have added a CSS tooltip to your HTML element with a title attribute, the default browser tooltip may still appear alongside your custom tooltip. This is because the title attribute is used by the browser to display the default tooltip, and it cannot be disabled. One way to hide the default HTML title is to change the title attribute to a data attribute as "title" -> "data-title" and you can access it in CSS as
content : attr(data-title) ;